# Edit resource dictionary style through c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, styles, microsoft-metro

I am designing a windows 8 app which has multiple levels. Each level has a number of buttons in it each with the style 'myStyle'.

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Ellipse StrokeThickness="4" Width="55" Height="55" Stroke="Aquamarine">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="GreenYellow"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF1E46FB" Offset=".5"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="GreenYellow" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I am trying to do is manipulate the code behind in c# to change the stroke color of all the buttons in each level. ie Level1 buttons have a red stroke, Level2 buttons have a green stroke etc... Currently I have the stroke set at Aquamarine by default.

I was wondering if anyone could give me any advice on how to do this. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: how are you mapping your button levels to the various styles?  Do you have different Styles for Level1, Level2, etc?  Is there a property on a ViewModel that you could then use a converter inside of your bindings to determine the color?   Simply setting Stroke={TemplateBinding BorderBrush} for instance would let you set each of your button color via a simple BorderBrush="Red", etc. With a Converter (to color) on the "level"property, you might be able to do this all with no code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the same style for all the levels. Here is the xmal.                   <Button x:Name="Peg1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="60" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="60" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Click="pegCheck"/>. By the way, myStyle resides within the StandardStyles.

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments, I think this should work for you.  In your template, use this for the Ellipse, instead of what you have now - everything else is the same:

```
<Ellipse StrokeThickness="4" Width="55" Height="55" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
```

Then you can assign colors to the buttons individually as you include them in the UI, e.g.,:

```
    <Button x:Name="b1" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" BorderBrush="Red">Level 1 Button</Button>
    <Button x:Name="b2" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" BorderBrush="Green">Level 2 Button</Button>
```

Or, you could make the same change to Ellipse and add additional styles based on the main one, for instance:

```
    <Style x:Key="Level1" BasedOn="{StaticResource myStyle}" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Level2" BasedOn="{StaticResource myStyle}" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
```

Then your buttons would look like:

```
   <Button x:Name="b1" Style="{StaticResource Level1}">Level 1 Button</Button>
   <Button x:Name="b2" Style="{StaticResource Level2}">Level 2 Button</Button>
```

Comment: Cheers for the advice Jim. Unfortunately I didn't explain myself fully. Throughout the level, I wish the button to change styles with accordance to the game rules eg it will go from myStyle to myStyle2, back to myStyle and then to myStyle3. As I only wish to manipulate the stroke for myStyle, setting the borderbrush in the UI is not the way I wish to proceed.

Comment: Also, The logic on the game makes use of the 'myStyle' x:Key. Therefore, adding myStyleLevel1, myStyleLevel2, myStyleLevel3 etc poses problems. Is there any other way to proceed..?

Comment: Using the logic seen here [link] (http://www.irisclasson.com/2013/01/04/example-winrt-changing-existing-style-resource-at-runtime-in-code-using-databindings/), I am able to change areas of the 'simple' styles at runtime. However, using the same logic, I am still up in the air as how to reference the ellipse stroke within a button style.

Comment: pull the markup into a window on your end, you'll see that changing the BorderBrush changes the Stroke because the TemplateBinding maps back to the BorderBrush property on the original button. In the code above, at runtime, you could do b1.Style = Resources["myStyle2"] as Style; but it would be more elegant bind to a property of your data model that keeps track of the "level" of a particular button, then when the level changes, the correct color is automatically bound. Would need more info on how you're tracking button levels though to provide sample code.

Comment: Cheers for the tips Jim. I am looking into what you have suggested and will let you know how it goes. Many thanks and enjoy your day :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue using your advice Jim. Applied templatebinding to my ellipse stroke in myStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" StrokeThickness="3" Width="55" Height="55" Margin="2.5">
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF9FA4A4" Offset="0.5"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Then used a foreach loop to set the foreground of all of my buttons(pegs) when the level loads.

```
foreach (Control p in Globals.allPegList)
        {
            p.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Globals.color1);
        }
```

Thanks for the help!

ps: Globals is just a namespace where I have a few global variables declared. color1 is a Color variable. allPegList is a list of all my buttons(pegs) in each level.